# How to calculate the hash of a string literal using only the C preprocessor?

Tags: c, string, hash, c-preprocessor

I need to get a string checksum or hash (or something equivalent) using just the C preprocessor, if possible.

The use case is as follows: I'm doing error logging on an embedded device with very limited memory and cpu.  I would like to define a `LogError()` macro which inserts `hash(__FILE__)` and `__LINE__` in a circular buffer (as 16bit numbers).  But `hash(__FILE__)` needs to be compiled to a constant; if the actual filenames are stored as strings in the program that would use too much memory.  The hash can be calculated using any method.

It is possible to `#define FILE_ID` with some unique number at the top of every file, and use that when logging, but that is not the preferred solution, it has a bit of a maintenance cost.  Is there a better method?

Comment: In C, expressions like `"foo.c"[0]+9*"foo.c"[1]` are not constant expressions, but when used in code, may still actually compile to constants.

Comment: What if two files have the same hash?

Comment: @immibis: I guess I'd have to take my chances; there aren't anywhere near 62k files.  Less worried about that than about someone accidentally defining FILE_ID to the same number in several files, if using the manual method...  I would probably write a python script to update the IDs in that case.

Comment: @greggo: Yes, definitely. `__FILE__[0]` seems to work.  Slight problem: `strlen(__FILE__)` is not a constant...

Comment: This is not possible. Your compiler may or may not fold your hash function invocation into a constant; I would rather bet on it not being able to do so. The solution with FILE_ID is actually very low maintenance if you use something like `-DFILE_ID=$$(myhashpgm $<)` in your makefile.

Comment: @n.m.: Good idea!  Post it as an answer if you want.  Of course a function call is unlikely to compile to a constant, I was assuming hash would be a macro along the lines of `#define hash(x) (x[0] != 0 ? x[0] ^ (x[1] != 0 ? x[1] ^ ... `.  That *does* compile to a constant, but it is not quite right.

Comment: Yes I have thought about this nethod, it's viable but the length of the filename is restricted. Then again, there's no *guarantee* it will compile to a constant.

Comment: This question is quite awkward since using the pre-processor to hash a string is useful in some cases - but almost certainly _NOT_ a good solution for this use-case. I added own answer, but wonder if your detailed use-case should be a separate question on calculating logging ID's for primitive architectures.

Comment: "there aren't anywhere near 62k files" — by birthday paradox, you'd have a roughly 50% chance of a hash collision with 300 files.

Comment: instead of `strlen(__FILE__)`, just use `sizeof(__FILE__)` and now it'll become a compile time constant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question *"How to calculate the hash of a string literal using only the C preprocessor?"*
is valid, however I think you're adding a red-herring by including details about `__FILE__` and logging ID's.

This means anyone answering needs to solve the problem you describe, or answer the question on hashing a string with the pre-processor *(which may not be a good solution in your particular case!)*.

As it happens, `__FILE__` expands to variable, not a literal string (GCC at least), so you will need to define the filename as a constant. You could use the build system to pass along a define for each for example.

As others have pointed out you can calculate the hash and pass this in via the build-system, although this avoids the question about hashing a sting literal.

---

Whatever the case, this question comes up when I searched for using the pre-processor for hashing, and none of the answers cover this, so heres is an answer that covers the string hashing part.

This is possible, albeit quite verbose

```
/**
 * Implement compile-time string hashing on string literals.
 *
 * This macro implements the widely used "djb" hash apparently posted
 * by Daniel Bernstein to comp.lang.c some time ago.  The 32 bit
 * unsigned hash value starts at 5381 and for each byte 'c' in the
 * string, is updated: ``hash = hash * 33 + c``.  This
 * function uses the signed value of each byte.
 *
 * note: this is the same hash method that glib 2.34.0 uses.
 */

#define SEED 5381

#if 0
// correct but causes insane expansion
#  define _SH(e, c) (((e) << 5) + (e) + (unsigned char)(c))
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
// Use statement-expression extension
#  define _SH(e, c) ({ unsigned int _e = (unsigned int)(e); (_e << 5) + _e + (unsigned char)c; })
#else
// use an inline function, the compiler will be able to optimize this out.
static inline unsigned int _SH(unsigned int e, unsigned char c)
{
    unsigned int _e = (unsigned int)e;
    return (_e << 5) + _e + (unsigned char)c;
}
#endif

#define _SH_1(a) _SH(SEED, (a)[0])
#define _SH_2(a) _SH(_SH_1(a), (a)[1])
#define _SH_3(a) _SH(_SH_2(a), (a)[2])
#define _SH_4(a) _SH(_SH_3(a), (a)[3])
#define _SH_5(a) _SH(_SH_4(a), (a)[4])
#define _SH_6(a) _SH(_SH_5(a), (a)[5])
#define _SH_7(a) _SH(_SH_6(a), (a)[6])
#define _SH_8(a) _SH(_SH_7(a), (a)[7])
#define _SH_9(a) _SH(_SH_8(a), (a)[8])
#define _SH_10(a) _SH(_SH_9(a), (a)[9])
#define _SH_11(a) _SH(_SH_10(a), (a)[10])
#define _SH_12(a) _SH(_SH_11(a), (a)[11])
#define _SH_13(a) _SH(_SH_12(a), (a)[12])
#define _SH_14(a) _SH(_SH_13(a), (a)[13])
#define _SH_15(a) _SH(_SH_14(a), (a)[14])
#define _SH_16(a) _SH(_SH_15(a), (a)[15])
#define _SH_17(a) _SH(_SH_16(a), (a)[16])
#define _SH_18(a) _SH(_SH_17(a), (a)[17])
#define _SH_19(a) _SH(_SH_18(a), (a)[18])
#define _SH_20(a) _SH(_SH_19(a), (a)[19])
#define _SH_21(a) _SH(_SH_20(a), (a)[20])
#define _SH_22(a) _SH(_SH_21(a), (a)[21])
#define _SH_23(a) _SH(_SH_22(a), (a)[22])
#define _SH_24(a) _SH(_SH_23(a), (a)[23])
#define _SH_25(a) _SH(_SH_24(a), (a)[24])
#define _SH_26(a) _SH(_SH_25(a), (a)[25])
#define _SH_27(a) _SH(_SH_26(a), (a)[26])
#define _SH_28(a) _SH(_SH_27(a), (a)[27])
#define _SH_29(a) _SH(_SH_28(a), (a)[28])
#define _SH_30(a) _SH(_SH_29(a), (a)[29])
#define _SH_31(a) _SH(_SH_30(a), (a)[30])
#define _SH_32(a) _SH(_SH_31(a), (a)[31])

// initial check prevents too-large strings from compiling
#define STRHASH(a) ( \
    (void)(sizeof(int[(sizeof(a) > 33 ? -1 : 1)])), \
    (sizeof(a) == 1) ? SEED : \
    (sizeof(a) == 2) ? _SH_1(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 3) ? _SH_2(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 4) ? _SH_3(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 4) ? _SH_3(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 5) ? _SH_4(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 6) ? _SH_5(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 7) ? _SH_6(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 8) ? _SH_7(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 9) ? _SH_8(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 10) ? _SH_9(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 11) ? _SH_10(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 12) ? _SH_11(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 13) ? _SH_12(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 14) ? _SH_13(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 15) ? _SH_14(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 16) ? _SH_15(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 17) ? _SH_16(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 18) ? _SH_17(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 19) ? _SH_18(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 20) ? _SH_19(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 21) ? _SH_20(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 22) ? _SH_21(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 23) ? _SH_22(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 24) ? _SH_23(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 25) ? _SH_24(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 26) ? _SH_25(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 27) ? _SH_26(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 28) ? _SH_27(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 29) ? _SH_28(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 30) ? _SH_29(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 31) ? _SH_30(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 32) ? _SH_31(a) : \
    (sizeof(a) == 33) ? _SH_32(a) : \
    0)
// last zero is unreachable

// only for comparison
unsigned int strhash_func(const void *str)
{
    const signed char *p;
    unsigned int h = 5381;

    for (p = str; *p != '\0'; p++) {
        h = (h << 5) + h + (unsigned int)*p;
    }

    return h;
}

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#include <stdio.h>

#define TEST_STR1 "Hello World"
#define TEST_STR2 "Testing 123"
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int A = STRHASH(TEST_STR1);
    unsigned int B = STRHASH(TEST_STR2);

    printf("String hash: const %u <- '%s'\n", STRHASH(TEST_STR1), TEST_STR1);
    printf("String hash: const %u <- '%s'\n", STRHASH(TEST_STR2), TEST_STR2);
    printf("String hash: dyn %u <- '%s'\n", strhash_func(TEST_STR1), TEST_STR1);
    printf("String hash: dyn %u <- '%s'\n", strhash_func(TEST_STR2), TEST_STR2);

#if defined(__GNUC__)
    printf("Is this known at compile time?, answer is: %d\n", __builtin_constant_p(A));
#endif
}
```

---

Note, for some reason Clang 5.0 prints `answer is: 0`, however on closer inspection is does in fact know the value at compile time, `__builtin_constant_p` just doesn't seem to work as GCC does.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking too much of the preprocessor.

Better just build each file with a 16bit checksum of its name defined as preprocessor
macro, as @n.m suggests.

One trifling difficulty for this solution is laying your hands on a
16bit checksum utility. The GNU `cksum` tool is just 32-bit.

But FreeBSD has a better one that lets you choose 16 or 32 bits. If your 
development system is a Debian derivative then
you can get it by:

```
sudo apt-get install freebsd-buildutils
```

Then run:

```
dpkg-query -L freebsd-buildutils
```

to see where the FreeBSD `cksum` has been installed. In my case, it is:

```
/usr/bin/freebsd-cksum
```

but you might find differently.

You direct FreeBSD `cksum` to produce a 16bit checksum by passing the option
`-o 1`. You can check its man page.

Take care when generating the preprocessor macro that defines a filename
checksum that you define the checksum *as a 16 bit unsigned int*, as that's
what you want. Should it come out as a plain decimal numeral, for instance,
it would default to signed int, which could cause you surprises.

Here's a sketch of the solution with GNU `make`:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%hu\n",FILE_CHKSUM);
    return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
.phony: all clean

SRCS = main.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
# Take the 1st word of the output of `echo <filename> | freebsd-cksum -o 1`
FILE_CHKSUM = $(word 1,$(shell echo $(1) | freebsd-cksum -o 1))

all: prog

%.o:%.c
    $(CC) $(CPPLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -DFILE_CHKSUM='((uint16_t)$(call FILE_CHKSUM,$<))' -c -o $@ $< 

prog: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) prog
```

Running `make`:

```
cc   -DFILE_CHKSUM='((uint16_t)3168)' -c -o main.o main.c 
cc   -o prog main.o
```

Run `prog`:

```
./prog
3168
```

Answer (score 0):

How to do this in CMake ? I can not figure out how to run script for every source file, and the result place as a value for -DFILE_CHEKSUM

Method with STRHASH, has a big limitation - it takes maximum of 32 characters as input, and when I have longer names, it just does not compile. I think that computing it before build and passing it as -D is beter approach, but I just can not manage to do it in cmake :(

Comment: never mind, I used 
```

static inline unsigned int strhash()
{
    const char *p = __FILE__;
    // ignore clang-diagnostic-static-local-in-inline - expected behaviour in this case
    static unsigned int h = 5381;  // NOLINT
    if(h!=5381)
    {
        return h;
    }

    for (;*p != '\0'; p++) {
        h = (h << 5) + h + (unsigned int)*p;
    }

    return h;
}
```
so after calculating it once in a file, I will just return fast